# Placing a colon after a link with title formatting hides it?

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I type

```
[Blender][1]
==

 [1]: http://www.blender.org/
```

Every thing works as expected:

---

## [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)

---

However, typing

```
[Blender][1]:
==

 [1]: http://www.blender.org/
```

Results in

---

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until this is fixed you can use the inline link syntax:

```
 [Blender](http://www.blender.org):
 ==
```

Which renders as:

---

## [Blender](http://www.blender.org):

---

#### Update

The problem was that due to a bug in the markdown code, the `Blender][1` part `[Blender][1]:` was considered a link hash (a normal link hash has the format of `[{id}]:`) and was stripped out.

Fix will be rolling out shortly. Watch for rev `2013.11.13.1150`